# unique and repeat column

Tags: mysql

Display only unique and repeat column

**sqlfiddle**: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/97bac/1

```
SELECT *
FROM `tbl_views_clicks`
WHERE `iDealID` =389
```

**result will be:**

```
|  iID | iUserID | iDealID | iCategoryID | iSubCategoryID |    vType | eGainType | iLocationID |              dtAdded | eDeviceType |
|------|---------|---------|-------------|----------------|----------|-----------|-------------|----------------------|-------------|
| 3410 |       1 |     389 |          79 |            135 | location |   Instant |        1403 | 2017-08-21T11:26:51Z |     Android |
| 3411 |       1 |     389 |          79 |            135 | location |   ByClick |           0 | 2017-08-21T11:26:52Z |     Android |
| 3412 |       1 |     389 |          79 |            135 |    gotit |   ByClick |           0 | 2017-08-21T11:27:19Z |     Android |
| 3413 |       1 |     389 |          79 |            135 |    gotit |   ByClick |           0 | 2017-08-21T11:27:28Z |     Android |
| 3414 |       1 |     389 |          79 |            135 |     back |   ByClick |           0 | 2017-08-21T11:27:32Z |     Android |
| 3475 |     250 |     389 |          79 |            135 | location |   Instant |        1403 | 2017-08-21T12:55:34Z |     Android |
| 3476 |     250 |     389 |          79 |            135 | location |   ByClick |           0 | 2017-08-21T12:55:36Z |     Android |
| 3477 |     250 |     389 |          79 |            135 |    gotit |   ByClick |           0 | 2017-08-21T12:56:39Z |     Android |
| 3479 |     250 |     389 |          79 |            135 |  website |   ByClick |           0 | 2017-08-21T13:04:30Z |     Android |
| 3480 |     250 |     389 |          79 |            135 |  website |   ByClick |           0 | 2017-08-21T13:04:54Z |     Android |
| 3481 |     250 |     389 |          79 |            135 |  website |   ByClick |           0 | 2017-08-21T13:05:06Z |     Android |
| 3482 |     250 |     389 |          79 |            135 |    gotit |   ByClick |           0 | 2017-08-21T13:05:16Z |     Android |
| 3483 |     250 |     389 |          79 |            135 |     back |   ByClick |           0 | 2017-08-21T13:05:21Z |     Android |
| 3484 |       1 |     389 |          79 |            135 |  website |   ByClick |           0 | 2017-08-21T13:06:28Z |     Android |
| 3485 |       1 |     389 |          79 |            135 |  website |   ByClick |           0 | 2017-08-21T13:06:36Z |     Android |
| 3486 |       1 |     389 |          79 |            135 |  website |   ByClick |           0 | 2017-08-21T13:06:44Z |     Android |
```

But I want like below:

- if vType is gotit or back first time then CustomType = 'Unique' else CustomType = 'Repeat'
- if vType is website first time then CustomType = 'Unique' else CustomType = 'Repeat'

**Unique & Repeat Result:**

```
|  iID | iUserID | iDealID | iCategoryID | iSubCategoryID |    vType | eGainType | iLocationID |              dtAdded | eDeviceType | CustomType
|------|---------|---------|-------------|----------------|----------|-----------|-------------|----------------------|-------------|-------------
| 3410 |       1 |     389 |          79 |            135 | location |   Instant |        1403 | 2017-08-21T11:26:51Z |     Android | Unique
| 3411 |       1 |     389 |          79 |            135 | location |   ByClick |           0 | 2017-08-21T11:26:52Z |     Android | Delete
| 3412 |       1 |     389 |          79 |            135 |    gotit |   ByClick |           0 | 2017-08-21T11:27:19Z |     Android | Unique
| 3413 |       1 |     389 |          79 |            135 |    gotit |   ByClick |           0 | 2017-08-21T11:27:28Z |     Android | Repeat
| 3414 |       1 |     389 |          79 |            135 |     back |   ByClick |           0 | 2017-08-21T11:27:32Z |     Android | Repeat
| 3475 |     250 |     389 |          79 |            135 | location |   Instant |        1403 | 2017-08-21T12:55:34Z |     Android | Unique
| 3476 |     250 |     389 |          79 |            135 | location |   ByClick |           0 | 2017-08-21T12:55:36Z |     Android | Delete
| 3477 |     250 |     389 |          79 |            135 |    gotit |   ByClick |           0 | 2017-08-21T12:56:39Z |     Android | Unique
| 3479 |     250 |     389 |          79 |            135 |  website |   ByClick |           0 | 2017-08-21T13:04:30Z |     Android | Unique
| 3480 |     250 |     389 |          79 |            135 |  website |   ByClick |           0 | 2017-08-21T13:04:54Z |     Android | Repeat
| 3481 |     250 |     389 |          79 |            135 |  website |   ByClick |           0 | 2017-08-21T13:05:06Z |     Android | Repeat
| 3482 |     250 |     389 |          79 |            135 |    gotit |   ByClick |           0 | 2017-08-21T13:05:16Z |     Android | Repeat
| 3483 |     250 |     389 |          79 |            135 |     back |   ByClick |           0 | 2017-08-21T13:05:21Z |     Android | Repeat
| 3484 |       1 |     389 |          79 |            135 |  website |   ByClick |           0 | 2017-08-21T13:06:28Z |     Android | Unique
| 3485 |       1 |     389 |          79 |            135 |  website |   ByClick |           0 | 2017-08-21T13:06:36Z |     Android | Unique
| 3486 |       1 |     389 |          79 |            135 |  website |   ByClick |           0 | 2017-08-21T13:06:44Z |     Android | Unique
```

**Final Result:**

```
|  iID | iUserID | iDealID | iCategoryID | iSubCategoryID |    vType | eGainType | iLocationID |              dtAdded | eDeviceType | CustomType
|------|---------|---------|-------------|----------------|----------|-----------|-------------|----------------------|-------------|-------------
| 3410 |       1 |     389 |          79 |            135 | location |   Instant |        1403 | 2017-08-21T11:26:51Z |     Android | Unique
| 3411 |       1 |     389 |          79 |            135 | location |   ByClick |           0 | 2017-08-21T11:26:52Z |     Android | Delete // delete this
| 3412 |       1 |     389 |          79 |            135 |    gotit |   ByClick |           0 | 2017-08-21T11:27:19Z |     Android | Unique
| 3413 |       1 |     389 |          79 |            135 |    gotit |   ByClick |           0 | 2017-08-21T11:27:28Z |     Android | Repeat
| 3414 |       1 |     389 |          79 |            135 |     back |   ByClick |           0 | 2017-08-21T11:27:32Z |     Android | Repeat // delete this
| 3475 |     250 |     389 |          79 |            135 | location |   Instant |        1403 | 2017-08-21T12:55:34Z |     Android | Unique
| 3476 |     250 |     389 |          79 |            135 | location |   ByClick |           0 | 2017-08-21T12:55:36Z |     Android | Delete // delete this
| 3477 |     250 |     389 |          79 |            135 |    gotit |   ByClick |           0 | 2017-08-21T12:56:39Z |     Android | Unique
| 3479 |     250 |     389 |          79 |            135 |  website |   ByClick |           0 | 2017-08-21T13:04:30Z |     Android | Unique
| 3480 |     250 |     389 |          79 |            135 |  website |   ByClick |           0 | 2017-08-21T13:04:54Z |     Android | Repeat
| 3481 |     250 |     389 |          79 |            135 |  website |   ByClick |           0 | 2017-08-21T13:05:06Z |     Android | Repeat // delete this
| 3482 |     250 |     389 |          79 |            135 |    gotit |   ByClick |           0 | 2017-08-21T13:05:16Z |     Android | Repeat
| 3483 |     250 |     389 |          79 |            135 |     back |   ByClick |           0 | 2017-08-21T13:05:21Z |     Android | Repeat // delete this
| 3484 |       1 |     389 |          79 |            135 |  website |   ByClick |           0 | 2017-08-21T13:06:28Z |     Android | Unique
| 3485 |       1 |     389 |          79 |            135 |  website |   ByClick |           0 | 2017-08-21T13:06:36Z |     Android | Repeat
| 3486 |       1 |     389 |          79 |            135 |  website |   ByClick |           0 | 2017-08-21T13:06:44Z |     Android | Repeat // delete this
```

**So it will be:**

```
|  iID | iUserID | iDealID | iCategoryID | iSubCategoryID |    vType | eGainType | iLocationID |              dtAdded | eDeviceType | CustomType
|------|---------|---------|-------------|----------------|----------|-----------|-------------|----------------------|-------------|-------------
| 3410 |       1 |     389 |          79 |            135 | location |   Instant |        1403 | 2017-08-21T11:26:51Z |     Android | Unique
| 3412 |       1 |     389 |          79 |            135 |    gotit |   ByClick |           0 | 2017-08-21T11:27:19Z |     Android | Unique
| 3413 |       1 |     389 |          79 |            135 |    gotit |   ByClick |           0 | 2017-08-21T11:27:28Z |     Android | Repeat
| 3475 |     250 |     389 |          79 |            135 | location |   Instant |        1403 | 2017-08-21T12:55:34Z |     Android | Unique
| 3477 |     250 |     389 |          79 |            135 |    gotit |   ByClick |           0 | 2017-08-21T12:56:39Z |     Android | Unique
| 3479 |     250 |     389 |          79 |            135 |  website |   ByClick |           0 | 2017-08-21T13:04:30Z |     Android | Unique
| 3480 |     250 |     389 |          79 |            135 |  website |   ByClick |           0 | 2017-08-21T13:04:54Z |     Android | Repeat
| 3482 |     250 |     389 |          79 |            135 |    gotit |   ByClick |           0 | 2017-08-21T13:05:16Z |     Android | Repeat
| 3484 |       1 |     389 |          79 |            135 |  website |   ByClick |           0 | 2017-08-21T13:06:28Z |     Android | Unique
| 3485 |       1 |     389 |          79 |            135 |  website |   ByClick |           0 | 2017-08-21T13:06:36Z |     Android | Repeat
```

**in short, all second entry must be defined as Repeat in CustomType column**

How can it be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT iUserID, iDealID, iCategoryID, iSubCategoryID, vType, eGainType, iLocationID, dtAdded, eDeviceType,CustomType
FROM
  (SELECT *, CASE
              WHEN INSTR(@VAR_COLUMN, vType) > 0 THEN 'Repeat'
              ELSE 'Unique'
          END CustomType, @VAR_COLUMN :=CONCAT(@VAR_COLUMN,CASE WHEN vType ='gotit' OR 'back' THEN 'gotit,back' ELSE vType END)
   FROM `tbl_views_clicks`,
     (SELECT @VAR_COLUMN :='')Z
   GROUP BY CASE
                WHEN vType IN ('gotit','back') THEN 1
                ELSE vType
            END,
            CustomType
   ORDER BY dtAdded)Z
```

Comment: Ok let me check.

Comment: Please check my output what i want:

Comment: `-> if vType is gotit or back first time then CustomType = 'Unique' else CustomType = 'Repeat'`
`-> if vType is website first time then CustomType = 'Unique' else CustomType = 'Repeat'`

Comment: yes, but gotit and back are same so in `back` there should be Repeat

Comment: Ok, but result should be only 4 rows

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152415/discussion-between-sagar-gangwal-and-pathik-vejani).

Comment: this result should be userwise